# How can I debug the value of a PL/SQL collection in Oracle?

Tags: debugging, collections, plsql, oracle10g

I'm debugging a procedure which ... returns certain values. The procedure seems to use `DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2` which was, till now unknown to me.

One of the out variables of the `DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2` procedure is a collection, and I want to examine that value is being returned into that - how can I observe/watch/examine this value ?

I use Allround Automations' PL/SQL Developer, but also have Oracle's SQL Developer as the tools with which I can use.

---

Tried iterating through the collection like so;

```
For Val In 1..M_Rec_Tab.Count Loop
 Dbms_Output.Put_Line( M_Rec_Tab(Val) );
end loop;
```

But that throws a `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'`.

M_Rec_Tab is declared as `Dbms_Sql.Desc_Tab2` type.

`Dbms_Sql.Desc_Tab2` declared as `desc_tab2 is table of desc_rec2 index by binary_integer`

I'm on Oracle 10g R2 ( 10.2.0.1.0 )

Comment: Iterate over the contents, using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to print out the value?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with Oracle collections or I'd be more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there...  Just one more step.  The definition of desc_tab2 is:

```
TYPE desc_rec2 IS RECORD (
   col_type            binary_integer := 0,
   col_max_len         binary_integer := 0,
   col_name            varchar2(32767) := '',
   col_name_len        binary_integer := 0,
   col_schema_name     varchar2(32)   := '',
   col_schema_name_len binary_integer := 0,
   col_precision       binary_integer := 0,
   col_scale           binary_integer := 0,
   col_charsetid       binary_integer := 0,
   col_charsetform     binary_integer := 0,
   col_null_ok         boolean        := TRUE);
```

So you can loop over the collection and output the values of each field in the record:

```
For Val In 1..M_Rec_Tab.Count Loop   
 Dbms_Output.Put_Line( '----- Record #'||Val||' -----' );   
 Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Column Type: '||M_Rec_Tab(Val).col_type );   
 Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Max Length: '||M_Rec_Tab(Val).col_max_len );
...
 Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Charset Form: '||M_Rec_Tab(Val).col_charsetform );
 Dbms_Output.Put_Line( 'Nulls Allowed: '|| case when M_Rec_Tab(Val).col_null_ok then 'Y' else 'N' end );
end loop;
```

Comment: That's the syntax I needed! Thx
table_type_var(index).col_name